# How do I improve my score in the Trapper Shingle challenge?

Tags: bastion

After triumphing over the Breaker's Bow challenge pretty quickly, I was feeling pretty proud of myself...only to get shot down as soon I got to the Trapper Shingle. In this room you have to use your Fang Repeater to shoot down small targets that appear...while running away from the collapsing floor. I can't seem to get the second place prize here, even with the repeater upgraded to hold 14 shots; as soon as I reach the last row of balloons, I don't have any time to fire shots because the floor starts falling too fast.

How do I improve my score here and win the first place prize? Are there certain upgrades I should be getting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In my experience, you need the upgrades to get first.** I was only able to get second without significant upgrades.

The upgrades that make this challenge easy:

- **55% faster reload**: Since you move so often in the challenge, a larger clip doesn't really help.
- **50% damage**: Wider attack spread makes the challenge harder.
- **55% faster reload**
- **50% damage**
- **Bolts Seek Out Foes**: Ricochet doesn't help, homing is an obvious benefit.

In actuality, you can get first without the Tier 5 upgrade and simply rely on the auto-targeting the game does once you are close to the targets.

Comment: Choosing these upgrades and realizing that I could hold shift to auto-target(took me the entire game to find that one out) made this   one really simple. Thanks!!

Comment: ha they mention it in the tute at the start!

Answer (score 9):

I made it without any upgrades with this technique:

1. Shoot while moving (use auto-target!)
2. While you are reloading use roll (evade) to move much quicker
3. When you reach the end of a line, stop moving! Don't enter the next line! Entering the next line triggers the floor to start falling from there, which means lost time which you can use better: Shoot as many targets of the next line as you can until the falling floor reaches you. Only then continue moving.

You gain so much extra time with this technique that you will be able to shoot every target.

Comment: Yeah, did it my first time with this technique.  And, FYI, on the PC, hold shift (defend) to engague auto-aim.  I couldn't even get close without it.

Comment: You can't shoot while moving with the Fang Repeater

Answer (score 3):

Fall off the starting platform until you are damaged below 33%.  With werewhiskey and autoaim(shift), you will easily get all 64 targets.

Comment: This tip got me all targets without any upgrades, at least after i noticed, that there is a key (R) for reloading without shooting all darts.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily remap the controls so your pinky doesn't get sore from holding down Shift. Right Mouse Button also is more useful to reload. Instead of shooting until you're empty and getting a slight pause before you run, shoot until you're almost empty, switch to running and reload on the go.